# React Context with useState in TypeScript requires initialState even when it's pointless?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Context to share `value` and `setValue` from the `useState` hook. The code below works but seems overly verbose. I'm new to TypeScript so I was hoping there was a more elegant way of writing it?

It's pointless to have a default value for `initState` as it gets overridden, but `createContext` errors if I don't pass it something.

```
interface IContext {
  value: number;
  setValue?: any;
}

const initState: IContext = {
  value: 2
};

export const AppContext = createContext(initState);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(2);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        value,
        setValue
      }}
    >
      <Stugg />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is simply forcing you to adhere to the contract, `createContext` expects *some* sort of initial value, and if it were any other language other than JS you'd find it would also throw a compiler error if you didn't provide it.

I wouldn't expect an error though if you go down the following route:

```
export const AppContext = createContext<Partial<IContext>>(null as IContext);
```

Comment: It does error: Type '{ value: number; setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.  TS2322

Comment: @Evanss d'oh, forgot to provide the type.

Comment: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<IContext>'.  TS2345

Comment: @Evanss try `null as IContext`? I'm not a day-to-day TS user so I'm probably just missing an obvious declaration somewhere. Guess it sort of defeats the purpose of your original point though, you still need to more or less define the type for even a `null` default value.

Comment: Maybe export const AppContext = createContext<IContext>({} as IContext); ?